# When does bind and unbind called in custom directives of Vue and how are they related to life-cycle functions (mounted / destroyed)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Say, I created a custom directive to handle window resize event and I wrote

```
Vue.directive('resize', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.resizeEvent = function() {
      vnode.context[binding.expression]()
    }

    // I would like it to be called in mounted
    Vue.nextTick(el.resizeEvent)

    window.addEventListener('resize', el.resizeEvent)
  },
  unbind(el) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', el.resizeEvent)
  }
})
```

I added `Vue.nextTick(el.resizeEvent)` because I would like this function is called when the component is mounted.

This directive works as expected so far. However, I do not have a clear idea about when the `bind` and `unbind` are called.

The documentation claimed that

`bind: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.`

`unbind: called only once, when the directive is unbound from the element.`

My question is, when exactly are `bind` and `unbind` called and how are they related to life-cycle hooks such as `mounted`, `created` or `destroyed` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ran some tests on a nuxt app. Here are my results:

1. created
2. bind
3. mounted

---

1. beforeDestroy
2. destroyed
3. unbind

---

I didn't test for update hooks.